# Swift Connect UITableView for multiple subcategories

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

Im looking for a solution, but I don't know what to search for anymore.

I want to display main categories with subcategories in a TableView. Not at the same time. First all main categories. If I click on a main category it should load the subcategories. Then when I click on a subcategory it should load its subcategories.

- MainCategory1

  - SubCat1

    - SubSubCat1
    - SubSubCat2
  - SubCat2

    - SubSubCat1
- MainCategory2
- ...

I have a NavigationController to switch between the main Category and the subcategories. Then I have a UIViewController with a TableView. In the TableView I display main categories.

At the moment: If I click on a main category it loads the SubViewController with the subcategories. This is the only possible solution I found so far.

The Problem is: I don't know how many subcategory levels each category has.

For my search keywords I found only other questions and tips with answers to create another TableView for one subcategory. But in this case I need to create for each subcategory a new TableView. I believe there is a better solution. 
(I tried with "reload table data" with new items but then I don't have the "Switch Back Function" of the NavigationController.)

So my question: How is it possible to load subcategories in the same View as the Main Category? (The swift back from a subcategory to a main category should still be possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case there are two possibilities.

> First Solution.

**Create two viewControllers.**

**1.) first for mainViewController. this will load all the data from web-service or from some other source and display only main categories.**

**2.) second viewController to display subcategories.**

Once user tap on any cell, just pass array of that subcategories to secondViewController, based on array just show subCategories.

once user tap on any subCategory, use the secondViewController again by creating its new object, and pass subSubCategories of that subCategory.

This way you can use one viewController multiple times, by creating its multiple objects.

OR if you already have main array of allCategories, you can create only one viewController and reuse it by just passing array of respective categories.

> Second Solution

You can create table expandable tableView like below link.
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/accordions/
(this link just for visual understanding)

Comment: Thank your very much. I made a fallacy. I need to use pushViewController instead of segues. :) In this case I can use one viewController multiple times as you suggested.